# Calculate optimal package size (Optimal Payload ) for maximize network speed

Tags: websocket, network-programming, webrtc, payload

I'm streaming tons of bytes form one PC to web application (javascript) (running on other machine/pc/mobile) through websocket.
Per my knowledge, there is a need to split the data into packages to maximize the network performance. My question is:

1. how I can obtain the payload size (optimal size) in real time to get the maximum speed!
2. is this different if I want to use WebRTC?

Answer (score 2):

You should send as many bytes at once as you can.  This not only optimizes sending on the network but also the software stack on the sending machine.  As for the packet size, you'll find that about 1300-1400 bytes is a good size on most systems and networks, because it's a bit less than one "MTU".

Comment: I meant frame size. Are you sure?, as I know, it is better to send small frames/packages instead of sending them all at once, in the network speed point of view!, where I can read the MTU, is this static number or change according to network bandwidth?
as I find http://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/maximum-transmission-unit : "Too large an MTU size may mean retransmissions if the packet encounters a router that can't handle that large a packet. Too small an MTU size means relatively more header overhead and more acknowledgements that have to be sent and handled."

Comment: @Joseph The documentation you're citing is about what TCP must do, not what applications must do. It is also a non-normative reference. The Path MTU is a property of the path, and the path is dynamic, so it can't be a static number.

Comment: He won't find anything about packet size, because he can't control it. TCP will.

Comment: @Joseph: the MTU is generally about 1500 bytes, and this is more or less fixed everywhere on the internet.  Now some pedants may come and say it is not a fixed value, but for most users it is around the same value.

Answer (score 1):

> Per my knowledge, there is a need to split the data into packages to maximize the network performance

There is indeed, but the TCP layer does that for you. The best you can do is provide TCP with as much data as possible, as quickly as possible, so it has the maximum choice.

> my question is: 1. how I can obtain the payload size (optimal size) in real time

You can't.

> to get the maximum speed?

You can't.

> 2. is this different if I want to use WebRTC?

No.

Comment: OK, but what if I send too large package that the other side can't handle?, as I read, then TCP will resend all again, ""Too large an MTU size may mean retransmissions if the packet encounters a router that can't handle that large a packet.".
 That mean every frame/package I'll send, the TCP will have to send/failed then resend again. Do I miss anything? if not, then, it is the reason I'm looking to find the optimal size before start sending.

Comment: @Joseph You can't. TCP won't let you. It has flow control. You will block. The stuff about send/failed/resend is a figment of your imagination. Don't worry about it. The optimal size for you to send is 'as much as possible'.

Comment: The problem that I see, if I change the frame size and  send 4K all the time, it does affect the speed then send 8K (fact!), maybe its the memory overhead/issue?!

Comment: @Joseph That's what I said. Sending 8k at a time is faster than sending 4k at a time, for a large number of reasons. If it isn't, there is something wrong with your code.